# InvalidAuthenticityToken exception when sending a HTTP POST

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, apache-httpclient-4.x

We're creating a Java client to interface with a Ruby on Rails server for an inventory system project (for school).

The client that we're using is supposed to do HTTP GET's to request information and HTTP POST's to update or create new information (yes, we know about HTTP PUT...).

Unfortunately, we are running into a InvalidAuthenticityToken error when we try to do a HTTP post. We authenticate through HTTP basic authentication and our controllers look like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #@user = User.all
    render :xml => @user.to_xml
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      render :text => 'Success!'
    else
      render :text => 'No success!'
    end
  end

private
  def authenticate
    logger.info("Entering Authen..")
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      logger.info("Time: #{Time.now}, username: #{username}, password: #{password}")
      User.authenticate(username, password)
    end
  end

end
```

The show action works perfectly and the authentication action is triggered with a valid username and password (e.g., working fine...). Our problem happens when we attempt to POST an update to the update action. When we attempt it, we get an InvalidAuthenticityToken exception. The following is from our development log:

```
#Successful GET
Processing UsersController#show (for 10.18.2.84 at 2010-11-24 19:02:42) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Entering Authen..
Filter chain halted as [:authenticate] rendered_or_redirected.
Completed in 3ms (View: 2, DB: 0) | 401 Unauthorized [http://10.18.2.84/users/show/2]

Processing UsersController#show (for 10.18.2.84 at 2010-11-24 19:02:43) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Entering Authen..
Time: Wed Nov 24 19:02:43 -0600 2010, username: admin, password: pass
  [4;36;1mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM "users" WHERE (user_name = 'admin' AND password = 'pass') LIMIT 1[0m
  [4;35;1mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) [0m
Completed in 18ms (View: 2, DB: 1) | 200 OK [http://10.18.2.84/users/show/2]

#Unsuccessful POST    
Processing UsersController#update (for 10.18.2.84 at 2010-11-24 19:03:06) [POST]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2", "first-name"=>"Macky"}

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken 
(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Our concern is that it isn't even attempting to authenticate the basic authentication -- it's skipping the filter and the entire controller as far as we can tell. Our code is pretty vanilla in the client (this is edited down for comprehensibility from what it actually is):

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        myCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials( username, password );

        //Set Provider
        provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        provider.setCredentials(scope, myCredentials);

        //Set Credentials
        httpClient.setCredentialsProvider( provider );

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first-name", "Macky"));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");

            //Set the post
            post = new HttpPost( url );

            post.setEntity(formEntity);

            response = httpClient.execute( post );
```

So, is it with Rails that we're doing something wrong or is it with the Java Jakarta client? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you also add the client code for GET request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you including the CSRF token in your POST data?

See this link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

By default `protect_from_forgery` is enabled which makes Rails require an authenticity token for any non-GET requests. Rails will automatically include the authenticity token in forms created with the form helpers but I'm guessing since you're building your own form to post, you're not including the token.